# Working of this circuit - Diodes

Tags: voltage, current, ac, relay, grounding

I have the below circuit where a single Phase AC input is given between Line and neutral.

[image]

But I have two questions:

1. Can someone tell me the working of this circuit and at what time the WEILD_DET pin will be active low?
2. The WEILD_DET pin goes into an MCU. There's no other description or instance of this in the schematic.

The application of this design is an EV Charger. I tried to relate the word "Weild/weld/wield" with the application of EV, but didn't get any results.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you heard of a bridge rectifier before?

Comment: At the peaks of input sine the WEILD_DET is high, I think.

Comment: Do you know which country that circuit was designed in? I suspect that "weild" could be the word for "mains" there. (And "DET" is short for "detect".)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thank you very much. That might be reasonable. The circuit seems to be for UK. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the value of the components, the circuit responds to the "maximum" (negative and positive) of the input voltage ...

[image]
<sub>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8xif.png</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Any idea on why I want this "maximum" value fed to an MCU in an EV charger application?

Comment: Vmax is used in EV chargers (DC part: 400V -> 800 V, bi-directional PFC system). See figures of https://recom-power.com/en/rec-n-electric-vehicle-chargers-switch-to-bidirectional-designs-227.html?0

Answer (score 3):

The circuit could be used to detect whether or not the AC supply is healthy.

WEILD_DET will be low when the AC voltage is *not* close to zero, and high when the AC voltage is close to zero.  Bear in mind that the AC waveform for a grid supply passes through zero 100 or 120 times a second.

Exactly what "close" is will depend on the specifics of the opto-isolator.

*It would be good if a large value resistor (a few hundreds of kilohms) was placed in parallel with C40.  Without it, somebody could get a nasty surprise when touching the circuit, even when it's unplugged from the AC supply.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Any idea on why I want this "maximum" value fed to an MCU in an EV charger application?